# NSCachesDirectory not a directory in my file system

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, caching

I'm trying to store something in my Caches folder on my iPad app.

```
    NSArray* cachePathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* cachePath = [cachePathArray lastObject];
```

And when I print out the returned filepath, I get:

> /Users/Gela/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/3FF7EB1A-49A9-4B13-ADC4-DF0662BA724B/Library/Caches

However, when I navigate to that folder on my hard drive, "Caches" is not a folder but a vague "document" file.

Any ideas why it's not a folder and how I can write to my Cache?

Comment: sometimes if you try to store `nil` in a directory in iOS sdk it messes up your directory and change it to some garbage file and all your data in that directory is lost.. seems like some bug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe `Simulator` does not have `Caches` dir. You try this on device...

You can access the `Caches` directory like this. I use this method for getting file data...

```
- (NSString *)getFileData: (NSString *)fileDirPath
{
    NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *err        = nil;
    NSString *fData     = @"";

    myPath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileDirPath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath])
    {
        fData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
        if(err) NSLog(@"getFileData() - ERROR: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"getFileData() - ERROR: This file '%@' does not exist",myPath);
    }
    return fData;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to find the path to the Caches directory. The problem is that "Caches" is NOT a directory on my hard drive. When I included the last line of your example code, I get an error saying the path is NOT a directory.

Comment: Yeah, see my update at the top. I was thinking, maybe Simulator does not have `Caches` directory...

Comment: I've done this on previous iPad apps using the iPad simulator on my computer and they have had Documents and Library/Caches directories. I think that the Caches directory on this particular app might have been corrupted?

Comment: Could be! You try to follow the dir filepath you get & see if it exists? if not create one & try running it again...

Comment: Yeah I followed the dir filepath and there is a file there called "Caches" but it is not a directory. Mac OS calls it a "document" file which is their way of saying they don't know what filetype it is.

Comment: I moved the Caches "document" somewhere else and created a new folder called "Caches". Also put a Snapshots folder in the directory and appropriate project folder. Seems to work now,  but I hope I didn't do anything wrong by removing the original Caches "document".

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Lion is trying to hide a caches directory from you.  Did you programmatically confirm that it existed and was not a directory?  I would not be surprised if it does not exist and you need to create it.  And, as mentioned, if it's corrupted, have you tried deleting it and seeing if you can recreate the problem?

Comment: I changed my settings so I could view the Cache folder. Yes, I used the NSFileManager to verify that the file at cachePath DID exist but WAS NOT a directory.