# Audio File Reading from Cache directory in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am downloading a audio-zip file from web and saving it in Cache, unzipped it in cache through code and now i just want to access audio from Cache memory. How can I do that?

Comment: where you store your file in app document directory?

Comment: I am using system cache directory for this process, download and unzipped successfully and now just want to read audio from cache on run time. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want that file permanently in your app then it would be better to save that file in document directory!

Comment: I am doing it for just test purpose, as I'm new with objective c, can you please tell that is it possible to access cache data at run time? I did not get any useful info over my reading!

Comment: it is my cache directory path: /Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3C27252-A1BE-440E-95BF-5AD9EA8BE0D2/data/Containers/Data/Application/019B243F-B62D-41F5-8E15-37B372A9FB6D/Library/Caches/phrases/say_thanks

Comment: OK then I think you can use same path for get audio files. It's ok kind of folder

Comment: can you please refer me to a suitable link from where i can get the idea? help would be appraised

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014770/nscachesdirectory-not-a-directory-in-my-file-system